# Toggle dropdown list of only one div from list of multiple divs when clicked in react

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to toggle hide and show unordered list when its sibling div is clicked. at first my code was toggling all divs and the I added unique identifiers for each list and modified my code but now nothing is getting toggled.
I would appreciate your help.

Child Component

```
import React from 'react';

const List = ({toggle, type, sum, i, hidden}) => {
    let visibility = {hidden} ? 'block' : 'none';
 
    return(
        <div>
            <div onClick={() => toggle(i)} style={{background: 'blue'}}>{type}</div>
            <ul>
            {
                sum.map((item) => {
                    return  <div style=style={{ display: visibility}}>{item}</div> 
                })
            }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default List;
```

Parent Component

```
import React from 'react'
import List from './List';
import listData from './listData.js';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            show: listData.map((element) => true)
        }
    }

    hideShow = (index) => {
        const newShowStatus = [...this.state.show];
        newShowStatus[index] = !this.state.show[index];
        this.setState({show: newShowStatus});       
    }
render(){
        const list = listData.map((item, index) => {
            return <List 
            type={item.type} sum={item.summary} 
            i={index} 
            toggle={this.hideShow.bind(this)}
            hidden={this.state.show[index]}/>                 
        })
        return(
            <div className="tc ma4">
                {list}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the css property dynamically, you can use dynamic render.

When you have `hidden = false`, tell `List` to render the `ul` tag.

```js
{!hidden && (
  <ul>
    {sum.map((item, index) => (
      <div key={item + index}>{item}</div>;
    )}
  </ul>
)}
```

Remember to add a unique key for every tag you render with the `map` function, this is very important!

[A working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-cookies-u2u6w?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Is there any way to make all the other opened lists to collapse when one list is opened?

Comment: if every list has a unique identifier, you can save a state in the app (parent) component with the id of the opened list, and when rendering each list check the id to determine if the list is opened or not. [I did answer something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67155066/8605592)

Comment: thanks man, I figured it out. I just needed to restore back all list status to close before I update the list to be opened.